# Concurrent kernels execution

Tags: concurrency, cuda

i want to know if using multiple cuda streams,provides the concurrency execution of the kernels ? or it provides only the Concurrency of copy and kernel execution ? 
accually i'm looking for a solution to execute multiple Concurrent kernels. 
Can anyone helps me ?

Answer (score 1):

CUDA streams are [required for most types of asynchronous concurrent execution](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution), except host/device concurrency.  Memcpy/compute overlap and concurrent kernels require streams.

Many folks have the mistaken idea that they can use concurrent kernel execution to run arbitrary kernels in parallel.  But concurrent kernel execution generally is only visible when the kernels to be executed are small in terms of their resource usage (blocks, registers, shared memory).  A kernel that uses a lot of threadblocks, a lot of registers, or a lot of shared memory may not run concurrently with other kernels -- because it is utilizing the entire machine by itself.

You can get started with concurrent kernel execution by studying and running the [concurrent kernels sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels) in the [CUDA sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html).

Comment: is there a way to verify if the kernels are really executed concurrently or not ?

Comment: You can use the [visual profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html).  It will show graphically the execution of the kernels in a timeline depiction.  Another approach would be to use a timing-based method, like the cuda sample does.

Comment: hello Robert, in cuda documentation, it is mentionned that if we use 2 streams (stream0 and stream1) like this way: we copy data in stream0 then we launch the first kernel in stream0 , then we recuperate data from the device in stream0, and then the same operations are made in stream1, this way , like mentioned in the book "CUDA by example 2010", doesn't offer the conccurent execution, but in the "concurrent kernels sample" this method is used and offeres the conccurent execution. So can you help me please to understand the difference beteween the two examples? thanks a lot for your help.